# c++ - Fill an array in a struct with data from ifstream

Tags: c++

I want to build a struct and fill an array in the struct from `ifstream`. However if I do a `*(reinterpret_cast<T*>(data));` the array is always null. I can better explain with sample code. Keep in mind I come from a C# background and I'm very new to C++. So if anyone can help or just give me a resource so I can learn about this specific problem, that would be great.

This reads byte data from the stream then creates a struct and returns it:

```
template<class T>
        T DFFLoader::ParseSection(UInt32 size)
        {
            char* data = new char[size];
            m_fileStream.read(data, size);
    
            T section = *(reinterpret_cast<T*>(data));
    
            delete[] data;
    
            return section;
        }
```

Frame List Struct:

```
struct FrameList
{
   int Count;
   Frame* Frames;
}
```

Frame Struct:

```
struct Frame
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
}
```

I use it like this (short example):

```
{
    int size = 40;
    FrameList flist = ParseSection<FrameList>(size);
}
```

Now `flist.Count` is correct (ex. = 3). But `flist.Frames` is NULL. I know for a fact the data is in the file.

Comment: What are you trying to do here ?  ` T section = *(reinterpret_cast<T*>(data));` 
And then you delete data. 
What does T do, does it have a constructor that copies the data?

Comment: consider using `std;:vector<char> buf(size);  m_fileStream.read(buf.data(), size);` then you don't have to manually write new/delete (more exception safe too then what you have now). And make a constructor for T that accepts a const std::vector<char>& that will copy the data (or you might write a move constructor where you move from the std::unique_ptr to data, which is even more efficient)

Comment: Saving pointers to memory isn't going to work. It is a miracle, that `Frames` is a null pointer and not pointer to invalid memory. And as miracles are extremely sketchy, I suspect, there is more to the code than it seems.

Comment: Thank you. I will give it another go and do as you guys said.